# How to Loop back after a condition?

Tags: php, loops

i want to make a loop to change color and when $a > 5 its back again to $a = 1 back to first color

Example : if $a=6 change to $a=1 and $a=7 change to $a=2 so if $a >5 can get color too

```
if ($a == "1") {
    $color = "btn-primary";
} elseif ($a== "2") {
    $color = "btn-success";
} elseif ($a== "3") {
    $color = "btn-info";
} elseif ($a== "4") {
    $color = "btn-warning";
} elseif ($a== "5") {
    $color = "btn-danger";
}
```

Comment: yes they inside a while

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use modulo to do this.

**Using `switch`:**

```
switch ($a % 5) {
    case 1:
        $color= "btn-primary";
        break;
    case 2:
        $color= "btn-success";
        break;
    case 3:
        $color= "btn-info";
        break;
    case 4:
        $color= "btn-warning";
        break;
    default:
        $color= "btn-danger";
        break;
}
```

---

**Using `if`:**

```
if ($a % 5 == 1) {
    $color = "btn-primary";
} elseif ($a % 5 == 2) {
    $color = "btn-success";
} elseif ($a % 5 == 3) {
    $color = "btn-info";
} elseif ($a % 5 == 4) {
    $color = "btn-warning";
} else {
    $color = "btn-danger";
}
```

---

*To be more simple,*

**Using array:**

```
$colors = ["btn-danger", "btn-primary", "btn-success", "btn-info", "btn-warning"];
$color = $colors[$a % 5];
```